# Insert item to array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 3 arrays which contains 5 elements each (max size is 5). What I wanted to do is to insert an item, e.g, to position 7. The end result is the item should be placed in 2nd array at index 2 and a 4th array is then created with 1 element (from last item of 3rd array).

```
                                result
array1                          array1
    - item1 (position 0)            - item1 (position 0)
    - item2 (position 1)            - item2 (position 1)
    - item3 (position 2)            - item3 (position 2)
    - item4 (position 3)            - item4 (position 3)
    - item5 (position 4)            - item5 (position 4)
array2                          array2
    - item1 (position 5)            - item1 (position 5)
    - item2 (position 6)            - item2 (position 6)
    - item3 (position 7)            - item3 (position 7) -> new_item
    - item4 (position 8)            - item4 (position 8)
    - item5 (position 9)            - item5 (position 9)
array3                          array3
    - item1 (position 10)           - item1 (position 10)
    - item2 (position 11)           - item2 (position 11)
    - item3 (position 12)           - item3 (position 12)
    - item4 (position 13)           - item4 (position 13)
    - item5 (position 14)           - item5 (position 14)
                                array4
                                    - item1 (position 15)
```

And, if wanted to get the item at position 12, then the result should be item3 of array3.

How can I do this in c++?

Comment: Do you _NEED_ to do it this way? If yes, why?

Comment: Are you open to crude-but-effective solutions like copying the arrays into a std::list, inserting the new element into the list, then copying back?

Comment: And do you have any preference about how you want to store these arrays, e.g. as vector<Item*>?

Comment: This seems completely pointless and arbitrary.   If inserting into `array2` means it is necessary to shuffle elements into `array3`, `array4`, etc, the it is easier to map the whole lot to a single array, and map indices.   This is exactly what happens in languages that manage multi-dimensional arrays using a single contiguous array.

Comment: @Beta Yes, I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us much about the real problem, but here's an outline of a general solution. To get access to position 13:

```
unsigned int n = 13;

// This is the zero-based index to find the array.
unsigned int i = n/5;

// This is the zero-based index of the element within the array.
unsigned int j = n%5;
```

For insertion, this function will insert item x at location k and return the last item (which had to be removed to make room):

```
int insert(Item *A, Item x, unsigned int k)
{
  Item ret = A[4];

  for(unsigned int j=4; j>k; --j)
    A[j]=A[j-1];
  A[k] = x;
  return(ret);
}
```

So if you have 3 arrays, to insert an item x at position 7:

```
Item y; 
y = insert(array2, x, 2);
y = insert(array3, y, 0);
```

Now create a new array4 by whatever method you like, and set array4[0]=y.